# Do things when Back Button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Inside of `navigationController`, when I'm in a `ChildViewController` and when the user taps on Back Button. I would love to send some data to the `parentViewController` before I go away.

Is any simple why to do this besides using

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear;
```

First, because this `ChildViewController` also has its own child, and when it gets pushed, `viewWillDisappear` gets called as well.

Second, when I user hits home button. it get called.(I guess)

Please, any reasonable and proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in any of following ways:

1. Send a notification when the second controller is going away and have the parent listen for it.
2. Create a delegate protocol that lets the second controller reference a parent method directly.
3. Use the parent's `viewWillAppear:` and check the `isMovingToParentViewController` property for whether it's just re-appearing.

and apply what is best for your value passing conditions and availability of values.

Comment: first two doesn't seem to work, because we don't know when the user tap on Back button, except detecting `viewWillDisappear`. But in `ViewWillDisappear` we don't know if it's getting popped or push to a child VC. So there is not way to send a notification or execute a delegate method.  the last one seemed awesome. how did you find those properties. did you read through the entire UIViewController reference?

Comment: Great, These are general properties that is consider to the View Life Cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice simple solution, that gets around the issue that viewWillDisappear is called when modalViewControllers are shown, or further viewControllers are pushed. E.g. detects the case where we're actually taken off the stack.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  NSUInteger ind = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] indexOfObject:self];
  if (ind == NSNotFound) {
      // do something, we're coming off the stack.
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that you don't need to subclass UINavigationController.

Source: http://objectivesea.tumblr.com/post/21705735018/poppingoffthestack

Comment: This seemed like a awesome trick, I would have pick you if wasn't for the answer @Arvind provided. `isMovingToParentViewController` and `isMoveFromParentController` looks more official.;)

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this problem using the [UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate).

In this case, you can use it to keep track of your controllers and you can implement `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` to transfer the data you need between the controllers. It's a lot cleaner than trying to hook into the `viewWillDisappear` notification, because you can isolate the data transfer logic within that delegate instead of having pieces of it in every controller.

Comment: I think that those two delegates are too simple, maybe useful for one level navigation... but doesn't seem to work at multiple levels. because we don't know if it get call because the child is poping or the parent is pushing. thx for the answer though.;)